# ASP.NET Query to get Random Object

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm looking for an efficient method of getting a single result from a SQL database randomly.

What I'm trying to accomplish is a "click here for new tip" where the tip is randomly selected from database. To simplify I don't care if this user has already seen this tip recently or ever before.

I realize I could get all tips then select one at random but that seems terribly inefficient, is there a built in or easy 'Random' function?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will it work for you (I assume you are using SQLServer) ?

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Your_Table ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Comment: I saw this before posing the question, it just sounded terribly inefficient. I found this document after: http://www.petefreitag.com/item/466.cfm

Comment: Maybe you can answer my question, from the documentation I read it sounds like this creates a new temporary id for all entries in the table before choosing one, is that really scalable?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the RAND function on your database: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177610.aspx. Very efficient!

Comment: `RAND()` doesn't always work as required (see http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/generate-random-records.aspx)